# combining different cell arrays into one in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab

I am trying to look for specific characters in an array and print the output into an excel sheet in the same order (i.e if there are elements in between without a match it is left blank).

I used the following code within the loop:

EDIT:

```
[num,txt,~] = xlsread('protein-peptides.xls')
for i=1:size(txt)
 str(i)=txt(i)
 expression='\w*Pyro-glu from E\w*';
 matchStr(i)=regexp(str(i),expression,'match','once');                             
 ArrayOfStrings=vertcat(matchStr{:}); 
end
```

After the loop:

```
xlswrite(filename,ArrayOfStrings,1);
```

And the output is like below.

1) The elements without a match are not shown as blank

2) Each word of the match is displayed in a different cell.

```
P   y   r   o   -   g   l   u       f   r   o   m       E
P   y   r   o   -   g   l   u       f   r   o   m       E
P   y   r   o   -   g   l   u       f   r   o   m       E
P   y   r   o   -   g   l   u       f   r   o   m       E
```

How do I get the blank spaces left out in the matrix and have the entire matching phrase in a single cell in the output?

I tried concatenation of cells but that is printing all the output in a single row but still each character in different cells

Comment: Why not just pass the cell array to `xlswrite`? Why do you need to combine it? `xlswrite(filename, matchStr)`.

Comment: Could you please share more of the enclosing code? I'm not sure what format your input data is in (is **txt** just a string?). Please share a sample of **txt** and the code for the **for** loop.

Comment: @Suever I did directly pass the cell array to xlswrite and it still has the same output.

Comment: @PaulVanWieren: I am reading the input txt from another excel file by xlsread. Please see the edit.

Comment: Bummer; I'm on OS X and it doesn't look like **xlswrite** is supported. Sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 1):

I know you'd probably prefer to use **xlswrite**, but I wasn't able to get this to work (at least on OS X). It appears that **xlswrite** automatically strips out empty cells, as you observed. It also appears to be spreading each cell over multiple columns, which is bizarre and different from the behavior I remember. I wonder if there was a recent update (I'm using R2015b).

I was able to get this to work using simple **fprintf** calls to write a CSV file, which can be opened in Excel. Note that the termination character (**\r**) is critical; empty cells do not seem to be preserved in Excel if this is replaced by a linefeed. I also refactored your code a bit.

```
% Load data from Excel file
[~, txt, ~] = xlsread('protein-peptides.xls');

% Perform analysis
expression='\w*Pyro-glu from E\w*';
for i = 1:length(txt)
    matches(i, 1) = regexp(txt(i), expression, 'match', 'once');
end

% Write data to CSV file
fid = fopen('test.csv', 'w+');
for i = 1:length(matches)
    fprintf(fid, '%s\r', matches{i});
end
fclose(fid);
```

**Input file rows**

- Pyro-Flu from E
- test
- Pyro-Flu from E
- test

**Output file rows**

- Pyro-glu from E
- 
- Pyro-glu from E
- 

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul, that helped. If I have multiple matches to be printed in adjacent columns how do I do it? If I create a mxn matrix with the mathces in individual columns matlab says that the function cannot accept ''cell'inputs. Can you suggest something for this?